# Identify this deity?

Tags: god

Can you help naming and listing god qualities [image]:

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be (Yellow) [Jambhala](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jambhala), the God of Fortune and Wealth.

Comment: Yes apart from the colour that does look like a mongoose in his left hand (as mentioned in the description in Wikipedia).